# vue component detect own index among siblings

Tags: vue.js, components, vuejs3

Suppose that I have some Vue components with this relationship. `CompA` uses a slot.

```
<CompA>
  <CompB />
  <CompB />
  <CompC />
</CompA>
```

If I wanted to know which numbered sibling each of these are I could hard code it like:

```
<CompA>
  <CompB i="0" />
  <CompB i="1" />
  <CompC i="2" />
</CompA>
```

...while defining an `i` prop on the definitions of both `CompB` and `CompC`.

Is there any method for these components to automatically detect what its own index is in the list of siblings which belong to its parent so that I do not need to hard code these indexes as props? Something that perhaps uses the `computed` option?

Answers specific to Vue 3 are okay.

**Edit**

The use case here is for building reusable widgets which conform to ARIA specifications where ARIA attributes need to reference unique IDs.

Example:

```
  <TabContainer tabsWidgetUnique="Tabswidget-1">
      <template v-slot:buttons="{ slotProps }">
        <TabButton :index="0" :slotProps="slotProps">Button A</TabButton>
        <TabButton :index="1" :slotProps="slotProps">Button B </TabButton>
        <TabButton :index="2" :slotProps="slotProps">Button C </TabButton>
      </template>
      <template v-slot:panels="{ slotProps }">
        <TabPanel :index="0" :slotProps="slotProps"> Panel A </TabPanel>
        <TabPanel :index="1" :slotProps="slotProps"> Panel B </TabPanel>
        <TabPanel :index="2" :slotProps="slotProps"> Panel C </TabPanel>
      </template>
    </TabContainer>
```

In this case I am manually setting the index of each so that in the components I can say:

```
<template>
  <div
    class="tab-panel"
    v-show="index === activeTab"
    tabindex="0"
    :id="tabsWidgetUnique + '-panel-' + index"
    :aria-labelledby="tabsWidgetUnique + '-button-' + index"
  >
    <slot />
  </div>
</template>
```

Comment: The answer should be NO, but more importantly, why do you need the indexes?

Comment: The use case here is setting relationships between elements in order to conform to aria patterns. IE an aria tabs pattern requires unique ids referenced by `aria-controls` and `aria-labelledby`. So, i'll edit my example to be more explicit about this, but the idea is that the first child of one container would be associated with the first child of another container and so on.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have any direct answer to your question, but I can offer you a different, and more practical approach.

```
<template>
  <TabContaier :data="tabData" :widget="1" />
</template>
<script>
 data() {
   return {
     tabData: {
        buttons: [
          { id: 1, label: Button A},
          { id: 2, label: Button B},
        ],
        panels: [
          { id: 1, content: "<h1>Title 1</h1><p>your content...</p>"},
          { id: 2, content: "<h1>Title 2</h1><p>your content...</p>"},
        ]
      }
   }
 }
</script>
```

Tab.vue

```
<template>
  <div class="tab-container">
    <div class="buttons">
      <TabButton
        v-for="button in tabData.buttons"
        :key="button.id"
        @click="activeTab = button.id"
      >{{ button.label }}</TabButton>
    </div>
    <div class="pabels">
      <TabPanel
        v-for="panel in tabData.panels"
        :key="panel.id"
        :class="{'is-visible': activeTab == pabel.id}"
        :content="panel.content"
      >
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
 data() {
   props: {
     tabData: {
       type: Object,
       default: {}
     },
     widget: {
       type: Number,
       default: null
     }
   },
   return {
     avtiveTab: 1
   }
 }
</script>
```

TabPabel.vue

```
<div class="panel" v-html="content"></div>
```

Let me know, if you have any question.

Comment: What if the panels, rather than container a simple string, need to contain HTML elements or other vue components? This is why in my prototype I have them use slots.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't declare a passed attribute as prop in child component it will be included in the `$attrs` property like :

```
this.$attrs.i
```

in option API or in composition one like:

```
setup(props,{attrs}){
  //then here you could use attrs.i
}
```